# Add existing view controllers in scrollview

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview

I have two view controllers and I wanted to add this as subview of my scrollview, but, when I add these view controllers the second controller is only displayed.

This is my code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

    [scrollView setBounces:NO];

    scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320*2, 460);

    controllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

    First *first = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"First"];
    [scrollView addSubview:first.view];
    [controllers addObject:first];

    Second *second = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Second"];
    [scrollView addSubview:second.view];
    [controllers addObject:second];
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You didn't modify viewcontroller's frame properly.

Comment: How should I do that?

Comment: It depends on where you want to place them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give you an example, you can adjust their frame according to your requirement.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

    [scrollView setBounces:NO];

    scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320*2, 460);

    controllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

    First *first = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"First"];
    [scrollView addSubview:first.view];
    first.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 460.0) ;
    [controllers addObject:first];

    Second *second = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Second"];
    [scrollView addSubview:second.view];
    second.view.frame = CGRectMake(320.0, 0.0, 320.0, 460.0) ;
    [controllers addObject:second];
}
```

Comment: Why do you not use the `addChildViewController()` method?